# Probability that a randomly selected integer from the set $\{1, \dots, 100\}$ is not divisible by $6$ or $9$.

Tags: probability

Slightly different variation to this question.

Compute the probability $P$ that a randomly selected integer from a set $\{1, \dots, 100\}$, is *not* divisible by $6$ ($A$) or $9$ ($B$).

I know that $P(A) = \frac{84}{100}$  &  $P(B) = \frac{89}{100}.$

I imagine the answer I am looking for is the Union of A & B.

So $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$

Am I on the right track?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I think your aproach is correct.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct, assuming that every number has $1/100$ probability to be selected. However, I think the faster approach is directly counting them as eleven numbers are divisible by 9 and only six of them are not divisible by 6, then the probability is $78/100$.